# Ninject Problem getting instances

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject

i got the tiny interface ITest:

```
public interface ITest
{
    void DoSomething();
}
```

and some implementations of ITest

```
public class Test : ITest
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Test2 : ITest
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Test3 : ITest
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Test4 : ITest
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now i setting up Ninject:

```
kernel.Bind<ITest>().To<Test>().Named("Test");
kernel.Bind<ITest>().To<Test2>().Named("Test");
kernel.Bind<ITest>().To<Test3>().Named("Test");
kernel.Bind<ITest>().To<Test4>().Named("Test");
```

And here is my first Problem.

If iam trying to get an instance using

```
ITest test = kernel.Get<ITest>("Test");
```

it results in a exception "Error activating ITest More than one matching bindings are available. ...". The documentation says: "Gets an instance of the specified service by using the first binding with the specified name."

Second Problem:

```
List<ITest> servicesList = new List<ITest>(kernel.GetAll<ITest>("Test"));
```

results in a exception "Error activating string No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable. ...". The documentation says: "Gets all instances of the specified service using bindings registered with the specified name."

Any ideas ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are giving all your instances the same name `Test` so it's normal that this would be ambiguous. Give them different names when registering your kernel:

```
kernel.Bind<ITest>().To<Test>().Named("Test1");
kernel.Bind<ITest>().To<Test2>().Named("Test2");
kernel.Bind<ITest>().To<Test3>().Named("Test3");
kernel.Bind<ITest>().To<Test4>().Named("Test4");
```

Now you can fetch your instances by name:

```
ITest test = kernel.Get<ITest>("Test3");
```

And to get them all you no longer need a name:

```
List<ITest> servicesList = kernel.GetAll<ITest>().ToList();
```

Comment: At first => Thanks for your answer ;) 

For the first Scenario i have to change my logic, no problem. But why does kernel.GetAll(typeof(ITest)) differs from kernel.GetAll<ITest>() ?

Comment: @dknaack, other than the strong typing at compile time, `kernel.GetAll(typeof(ITest))` and `kernel.GetAll<ITest>()` return absolutely identical object instances into the resulting list at runtime.

Comment: kernel.GetAll<ITest>() works just fine but
kernel.GetAll(typeof(ITest)) will throw the exception "Error activating ITest More than one matching bindings are available. ..."

And why does ".Named(string)" exists when i cant bind more than one Type ? And why does kernel.GetAll(typeof(ITest)) differs from kernel.GetAll<ITest>() ? According the documentation the Get method will "Gets an instance of the specified service by using the FIRST binding with the specified name".

Comment: @dknaack, I didn't get any such exception when testing your code. Both worked just fine. I downloaded the latest Ninject.MVC3 Nuget and used the registration showed in my answer.